# Failed to fetch http://hostname/swagger.json

Tags: http, https, swagger-ui, flask-restful

I am new to flask rest api. I tried to deploy my flask rest api using helm. My company has DNS set up which always route http to https. I failed at loading http://hostname/swagger.json. Here is the screenshot for this:

[screenshot for swagger UI error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtajf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

```
from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix   
 # For HTTPS of serving docs
 app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app, x_proto=1, x_host=1)  # type: ignore
```

Answer (score 0):

If your backend always redirects to the `https://` version, you should fetch `https://hostname/swagger.json`.  Or, at least make sure your fetch utility can handle redirects.